# The <CATALINA_HOME>/conf/server.xml can't be read

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

For some reason i cant get tomcat 8 to run on netbeans...it runs just fine on localhost:8080. But wont work on netbeans. Im running ubuntu 16.04.

catalina variables are set like this :

```
      CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat8
      CATALINA_BASE=/usr/share/tomcat8
```

share/tomcat8 doesnt have conf file, i think this is the issue, conf file is at var/lib/tomcat8.
How can i solve this? tried setting catalina_base and _home to var/bin/tomcat8, but it wont work

Answer (score 7):

Hello in your `/usr/share/tomcat8` don't have the `conf` folder, use the code below to create a simbolic link of tomcat8 configurations.

`ln -s /etc/tomcat8 /usr/share/tomcat8/conf`

[Link](http://lifeofpentester.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/confserverxml-cant-be-read-error.html)

Answer (score 2):

For me this solution Worked:

$ sudo chown -R USERNAME /var/lib/tomcat8 
$ sudo chown -R USERNAME /usr/share/tomcat8 
$ sudo chown -R USERNAME /etc/tomcat8 
$ sudo chown -R USERNAME /var/log/tomcat8

[link](https://gist.github.com/alexislucena/de7d4f61f76b89853ae443dca3a0aa96)

Comment: This is the correct solution. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this tip but

1. You have to do with 'sudo'
2. You have to give read right to /etc/tomcat8 (chmod +r ...)

Comment: This is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the terminal:

For Tomcat version 9

```
ln -s /etc/tomcat9 /usr/share/tomcat9/conf
```